# How to retry an upstream task?

Tags: airflow

`task a > task b > task c`

If C fails I want to retry A.  Is this possible?  There are a few other tickets which involve subdags, but I would like to just be able to clear A.

I'm hoping to use `on_retry_callback` in task C but I don't know how to call task A.

There is another question which does this in a subdag, but I am not using subdags.

I'm trying to do this, but it doesn't seem to work:

```py
def callback_for_failures(context):
    print("*** retrying ***")
    if context['task'].upstream_list:
        context['task'].upstream_list[0].clear()
```

Comment: I no longer believe this is easily possible.  I also don't believe that the system was designed for this.

Comment: It's technically possible, but I would really recommend against it. You'll end up confusing Airflow and likely end up in an infinite loop should task C always fail.

You might want to look at a SubDag as I believe they can be treated as a "whole" and have retries tied to them.

Answer (score 0):

As other comments mentioned, I would use caution to make sure you aren't getting into an endless loop of clearing/retries. But you can call a bash command as part of your on_failure_callback and then specify which tasks you want to clear, and if you want downstream/upstream tasks cleared etc.

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


def clear_upstream_task(context):
    execution_date = context.get("execution_date")
    clear_tasks = BashOperator(
        task_id='clear_tasks',
        bash_command=f'airflow tasks clear -s {execution_date}  -t t1 -d -y clear_upstream_task'
    )
    return clear_tasks.execute(context=context)


# Default settings applied to all tasks
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(seconds=5)
}


with DAG('clear_upstream_task',
         start_date=datetime(2021, 1, 1),
         max_active_runs=3,
         schedule_interval=timedelta(minutes=5),
         default_args=default_args,
         catchup=False
         ) as dag:
    t0 = DummyOperator(
        task_id='t0'
    )

    t1 = DummyOperator(
        task_id='t1'
    )

    t2 = DummyOperator(
        task_id='t2'
    )
    t3 = BashOperator(
        task_id='t3',
        bash_command='exit 123',
        on_failure_callback=clear_upstream_task
    )

    t0 >> t1 >> t2 >> t3
```